# Need to join 5 tables and produce output in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need help to join 5 tables and produce output in MySQL. Below are the details:

[image: Table description]

Supposedly if the user is associated with 2 Devices and 2 Groups, the output should be as follows:

Some user name 1, Some group name 1, Some group name 2, Some device name 1, Some device name 2

I had been able to join 3 tables to and got the output. But still my requirement is not satisfied. Below is what I had written:

```
SELECT  um.user_name as username, ep.device_name as devicename
    FROM  user um
    INNER JOIN  user_device_association uea  ON um.user_id = uea.user_id
    INNER JOIN  device ep  ON uea.endpoint_id = ep.endpoint_id
    WHERE  (um.user_id IN (
                SELECT  user_id
                    from  user)
```

I appreciate any help in this regard

=======================================================

I had been able to get the result by joining multiple tables based on the response received. However, I need the response as a JSON object.

I need to group the results based on user_name. For ex: I have an user A associated with groups G1 and G2, and the same user A is associated with devices D1 and D1. I'm trying to use Concat and Group concat to group the results based on User A, but need help to proceed further. Here is the sample code [incomplete though]:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
      '[
      name = ', u.user_name,
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'Group ID', g.group_id,
          'Group Name', g.group_name
        )
      ),
      ']'
    ) as user_details
FROM User AS u
JOIN User_group AS ug  ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
JOIN Group AS g        ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
JOIN User_device AS ud ON u.user_id = ud.user_id
JOIN Device AS d       ON ud.device_id = d.device_id
```

Below is what is the desired result:

```
User:
Name: 
    User_Name
    Group:
        Group 1
        Group 2
    Device:
        Device 1
        Device 2
```

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` clause; it does not provide anything useful.

Comment: Ok, but even then my requirement is not satisfied. I need the output as follows:
Some user name 1, Some group name 1, Some group name 2, Some device name 1, Some device name 2

Comment: I don't understand your indented "desired result" -- it implies that "Group 2" has some devices, but "Group 1" does not.

Comment: There was an error in the format, which I have corrected now. Groups and Devices are associated to User. I need help to get the desired JSON output

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?  `JSON` functions are relatively new.  Perhaps you want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the documentation. I need help to build the JSON structure from the output of the query. If it is not possible with the nested queries, I should be fine if it is a stored procedure as well that produces the desired result. I need help to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user_name, g.group_name, d.device_name
    FROM User AS u
    JOIN User_group AS ug  ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
    JOIN Group AS g        ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
    JOIN User_device AS ud ON u.user_id = ud.user_id
    JOIN Device AS d       ON ud.device_id = d.device_id
```

Even without a `WHERE`, this should list all combinations (according to the 'association' tables) of users, groups, and devices.

`WHERE` *filters* out things that don't match.  The absence of `WHERE` is to fetch "everything".

Comment: I was able to get the desired result, but I need to group the results based on user_name. For ex: I have an user A associated with groups G1 and G2, and the same user A is associated with devices D1 and D1. I'm trying to use Concat and Group concat to group the results based on User A, but need help to proceed further. Here is the sample code [please find it in the next comment]:

Comment: SELECT 

CONCAT(
  '[
  name = ', u.user_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'Group ID', g.group_id,
      'Group Name', g.group_name
    )
  ),
  ']'
) as user_details


    FROM User AS u
    JOIN User_group AS ug  ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
    JOIN Group AS g        ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
    JOIN User_device AS ud ON u.user_id = ud.user_id
    JOIN Device AS d       ON ud.device_id = d.device_id

Below is what is the desired result:

User:
Name: User_Name
 
Group:
 Group 1
 Group 2
 
Device:
 Device 1
 Device 2

Comment: @Vikram - Are you looking at all users associated with any two groups and any two devices?  Or looking at specifically 'group_name IN ('G1', 'G2')` and similarly for two specific devices at the same time?

Comment: I'm looking at any User associated to Groups and Devices. Each User might be associated with any number of Groups and Devices [and not necessarily 2]